# Convert UTF-8 literals to readable string, C#?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8

I have a string as follows

```
const string nameString = @"\xda\xa9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1";
```

I tried:

```
var name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nameString));
```

Not work.

You can find real characters here:
https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal
e.g:
`U+0631 ر   \xd8\xb1`

How can we convert it to readable string in C#?

Comment: You should understand that this is a NOP `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nameString))`. They are complete inverses of each other (except if passed `null`).

Comment: Also, \xXX is not C#. Now, the answers can unravel the given format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we have to *parse*: each `"\xa9"` should be converted into `byte` `0xa9`

```
  const string nameString = @"\xda\xa9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1";
```

We can do it with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
  byte[] data = Regex
    .Matches(nameString, @"\\x(?<value>[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => (Convert.ToByte(match.Groups["value"].Value, 16)))
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look at the data:

```
  // da a9 d8 a7 d8 b1 d8 a8 d8 b1
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", data.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))));
```

Finally, we want to encode `data` to string; assuming that we should use `UTF8`:

```
  string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

  Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Outcome:

```
  کاربر
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `@` sign causes escape sequences to be interpreted literally. Remove `@` sign to achieve desired result.

For more information see [@ (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

> The @ character in this instance defines a verbatim string literal. Simple escape sequences (such as "\" for a backslash), hexadecimal escape sequences (such as "\x0041" for an uppercase A), and Unicode escape sequences (such as "\u0041" for an uppercase A) are interpreted literally.

Comment: No change, I used
```const string nameString = "\xda\xa9\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1";
            var name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nameString));
            Console.WriteLine(name);```